# No default constructor found when using ModelAttribute with a Boolean object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem in my Spring application, I am trying to receive an attribute that is a boolean, I've used the Object Boolean but I'm getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Boolean]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Boolean.<init>()
```

This is how I am creating the controller method:

```
protected String method(Model model,
                                    @ModelAttribute("attr1") Object1 attr1,
                                    @ModelAttribute("attr2") Object2 attr2,
                                    @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> values,
                                    @ModelAttribute("theattrthatdoesnotwork") Boolean theattrthatdoesnotwork) {
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can't you use Booleans as Model Attributes?, I'm a bit new to Spring.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@RequestParam Boolean theattrthatdoesnotwork` instead of `@ModelAttribute`. `@ModelAttribute` have sense when you have let's say 5 fields and then you don't want to write all of them as `@RequestParam`. Your error is telling you exactly problem. You cannot annotate parameter with `@ModelAttribute` if it does not have default `constructor` (and `Boolean` obviusly don't have it). If you want to pass your `Boolean` as `body` and not as `param` you should use `@RequestBody` and not `@ModelAttribute`. You can notice that `attr1` is also shown in `url`.

Comment: The problem I have with Request Param is the parameter is shown in the url and I do not want it to be shown, if there's a way for it to not be shown I'm up for it!